# What is known about collineation groups in general?

Tags: reference-request, projective-geometry, automorphism-group, finite-geometry

Is there any reference for collineation groups of finite projective planes?

By collineation of a projective plane $\pi=(P,L,i)$ I mean a bijective function $f:P\to P$ which preserves collinearity.

Are there theorems like "collineation groups of finite projective planes are solvable" or "have odd order" or something similar? I can't find anything online about this topic.

Also, if we consider maps $f:P\to P$ which only preserve incidence, what can we say?

Thanks!

Comment: What would if mean for a map from $P \to P$ to "preserve incidence"; incidence between what?

Comment: To your second question: aren't they the same as collineations? Or how do you mean that?

Comment: @MorganRodgers If a line $l$ is a set of points then $f:P\to P$ preserves incidence if $f(p)$ is incident with $f(l)$ whenever $p$ is incident with $l$

Comment: Because there are so many different types of projective planes, and their classification is far from complete, there is a lot that can be said of their possible collineation groups. Here is an excellent reference due to Kantor https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.78.8269&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: If you think of a line as a set of points, then $f$ is a collinearity if for each line $l$, $f(l)$ is again a line. It is trivial that $p$ incident with $l$ will imply $f(p)$ incident with $f(l)$ because of how you are defining $f(l)$ (as $\{ f(p) : p \in l \}$ presumably).

Comment: There are LOTS of references if you type `collineation group finite projective plane` into Google Scholar.